# How to make eclipse launch a program in the eclipse workbench from the command line?

Tags: eclipse

How do I make eclipse launch a program in the eclipse workbench from the command line?

Specifically, I would like to run a command from the shell that causes my eclipse instance (which is already open) to run a particular program. If there is no program to do this from the shell, is there some RPC API that eclipse provides to make such a program?

I do not want to make a plugin. It must be a separate process that controls eclipse.

Answer (score 5):

Eclipse Remote Control seems that it might do the trick https://github.com/marook/eclipse-remote-control from the Read me file.

> Introduction
>
> Eclipse plug-in project which adds remote control features to eclipse.
>   Commands can be sent via the eclipse remote control client to a
>   running eclipse instance.

I have not tried it myslef but I ran into it trying to figure out how to write an ant task that triggers .launch file

Comment: I thought this was a great suggestion so wanted to try it out. However, I could not get the plugin to work for Eclipse Indigo or Juno :(.

I am on OSX Mountain Lion with JDK 1.6.x and attempted the above with a fresh install of Eclipse Juno and Indigo with a new workspace.

Comment: When the plugin ist installed, and you have a run configuration already defined inside eclipse, it should be as simple as executing the follwing from the commandline:
    java -jar eclipse_remote_control_client.jar execute_command <YourLaunchConfifgName>

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Product Configuration](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.pde.doc.user/guide/tools/editors/product_editor/configuration.htm)

1º Create a new Product Configuration (Ctrl+N), and select "Use a launch configuration" (or another option, if it's more convenient) on the first page of the wizard.
2º In the Exporting section you should be able to export your product using the "Eclipse Product export wizard".
3º To run the product, follow [this instructions](http://wiki.eclipse.org/RCP_FAQ#How_can_I_deploy_my_RCP_app.3F)

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

First create a batch file and save it in a location.

For example if I want to invoke notepad , I will write in the batch as follows

start notepad

In eclipse, you can configure external tools. 
 
Goto Run -> External Tools -> External Tools Configurations.

You will be presented with a Dialog box.

Now Click on the New Configuration Icon.
In the right pane of Window you can assign a configuration Name.
In the Location Text Box, Click on the "Browse File System" Button, and select the batch file you have created earlier.

In the Common Tab, uncheck "Launch In Background".
You can set this configuration in Favourites menu, by clicking the checkbox "External Tools" under Common Tab.
Click on Apply.

Now you can Run your required application.
 This is for Windows only.
 I don't have any idea of this for **Linux Machines**.

Answer (score 0):

Not a complete answer, but here are some things I've come across with Eclipse:

In general, you can open Eclipse from the command line with something like:

`java -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5 -Dhelp.lucene.tokenizer=standard -Xms40m -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -cp plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main`

That Main launcher takes an `-application` flag where you can pass what I think are plugins (not sure).  I've typically used this to run Ant within Eclipse:

`java -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5 -Dhelp.lucene.tokenizer=standard -Xms40m -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -cp plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main -application org.eclipse.ant.core.antRunner -buildfile build.xml`

I have no idea how to manipulate a running Eclipse instance, and I don't know if you can achieve your goals through an Ant script, but I thought these might be fruitful avenues.

Answer (score 0):

Addition to ams' answer, marook's plugin just support very few commands.

`open_file` and `execute_command` with `RUN/DEBUG/PROFILE`

And marook also have a blog post about how to implement more command http://pielmeier.blogspot.com/2010/07/implementing-new-eclipse-remote-control.html

But as we all know, Eclipse plugin development is quite heavy weight.

So, I suggest just use `execute_command` with `RUN` by marook's plugin. The further function to Eclipse IDE, can be done by **`Eclipse EASE script engine`**. Write a light weight script and then `RUN` by marook's plugin, to avoid Eclipse plugin development.

More information about EASE can be found at:

https://opensource.com/life/16/2/how-use-python-hack-your-ide

There is also javascript script support:

https://git.eclipse.org/c/ease/org.eclipse.ease.scripts.git/tree/JavaScript%20Beginner%20Tutorial/02%20File%20IO/05%20Create%20sample%20project%20(using%20modules).js

Answer (score -1):

Here you have a series of examples: http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0014.html

Basically, you use:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
```

Comment: That's not what I mean't, I'm afraid. What you are describing is how you execute a shell command from java. What I want to know is, how do you get a separate program (like some shell command) to tell eclipse to run another (java) program (perhaps connected to its debugger)?