# Runnig eclipse from Jenkins

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, hudson, jenkins

I have installed the Jenkins on my windows machine. 
I am currently doing the functional testing of a website and i have created all the test cases using selenium . I ran all these testcases using eclipse with testng plugin.

Now is there any way where i can run these testcases in eclipse from Jenkins itself i.e Can i control the eclipse from Jenkins.
I am trying hard now and able to run it using batch command( i have written all the commands in a batch file to run the eclipse and selenium driver and that batch file is executed from  Jenkins ) but i am in search of a plugin where i can run directly the eclipse , selenium web-driver using that plugin.
Please see to this issue.

Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at this question : 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7161978/how-to-make-eclipse-launch-a-program-in-the-eclipse-workbench-from-the-command-l

Comment: it is using a batch file to run  eclipse..But i need jenkins to run it directly through a plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right lines with a batch file, but I recommend you use Ant or Maven instead of Eclipse - they are the standard way of scripting builds in Java, and they have good Jenkins support.

Here is a plugin for Maven to start up Selenium before the tests: http://mojo.codehaus.org/selenium-maven-plugin/

Here is how to run your TestNG tests using Maven: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/testng.html